# Proper way to handle constants with multiple possble values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

We are adding some constants to our app for possible return values for particular properties on API calls and I would like to figure out the best way to handle values that could have several possible values.

To better illustrate what I mean, consider the code below:

```
export class PlayerNameConstants {
    public static readonly LEBRON = 'Lebron James';
    public static readonly SHAQ = 'Shaq';

    // I know this isn't valid typescript
    public static readonly JORDAN = 'Michael Jordan' | 'MJ';
}

// In some other file
apiCallToReturnValue()
    .then(val => {
        if (val.playerName === PlayerNameConstants.JORDAN) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    })
```

In the above code, what would be the best way to capture in our constant that `JORDAN` could be either 'Michael Jordan' or 'MJ'? It would be nice if I checking `JORDAN` maintained the same call signature as the other constants, rather than making it into a function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your constants as arrays instead of strings.  Then check to see if it matches anything in the constant array.  Something along the lines of this:

```
export class PlayerNameConstants {
    public static readonly LEBRON = ['Lebron James'];
    public static readonly SHAQ = ['Shaq'];
    public static readonly JORDAN = ['Michael Jordan', 'MJ'];
}

// In some other file
apiCallToReturnValue()
    .then(val => {
        if (PlayerNameConstants.JORDAN.includes(val.playerName)) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a function instead of a const value, e.g.

```
export class PlayerNames {

    public static IsJordan(name: string): boolean { return name == 'Michael Jordan' || name == 'MJ'};
}

// In some other file
apiCallToReturnValue()
    .then(val => {
        if (PlayerNames.IsJordan(val.playerName)) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    })
```